# How to get a 2-project view

Tags: c#

I am a beginner in Visual Studio. I followed the tutorial provided by Microsoft and encounter a problem as follows.

[image: Image on tutorial]

All I can get is one of the following.

[image: What I got]

I'd like to ask how to get the 2 projects under the solution?

Ben

Comment: Right click on the solution ad then `Add->New Project`, Choose your project from the available project template, done!

Comment: The problem is that you have two different solutions. Pick one and like mentioned by @SalahAkbari add project

Comment: You have thee projects.  You need to create a new project QuickSolution and add the QuickTest and QuickDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your pictures, it appears you have two different solutions, you can actually create two projects from a single solution. Use the **QuickDate** Solution as your main solution, then follow these simple steps:

1. Right-Click on the solution (The first option stating the number of projects (**1 of 1 Project**))
2. Select Add

3 From the add options, select existing project

4. Your file explorer will be opened, locate the path where you save the **QuickTest** project
5. Select the .cproj file.

And you are good to go!. Two projects, one solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a solution and your projects to solution by command-line:

```
//create a solution
dotnet new sln --name QuickSolution
//create a src folder
mkdir src
//Change directory to src
cd src
//Now put your projects into src folder and them to solution like below:
dotnet sln ..\QuickSolution.sln add .\QickDate\QickDate.csproj .\QickTest\QickTest.csproj
```

Answer (score 0):

First Create a project and give a solution name for your project. By default it is the same as the project name. After creating first project you can add another project under this solution. To do this right click on the solution name then add then new project. Then select your project type(such as console app/mvc/class library whatever). Give your project name as usual you create your first project.

Answer (score 0):

I follow the steps below to successfully create.

- Create a project QuickSolution Right-click on the top line
  QuickSolution.sln
- Create the 2 project "QuickDate" & "QuickTest"
- Quit Visual Studio
- Edit QuickSolution.sln
- Delete the lines about "QuickSolution"
- Delete the project folder for "QuickSolution"